# Accessing Payload using JAVA (MULE)

Tags: java, soap, mule, payload

I'm currently working on a flow using MULE and I need to get some information using a java class. To do some validations, transformations and then call a stored procedure in an Oracle database, I need to get the information stored in `<type:Data>` , this is the flow:

```
<flow name="INSERT">
    <http:listener config-ref="CONFIG_1" path="/afis/afisInsert" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:proxy-service port="InsertDATA" namespace="http://www.morpho.com/SIIMInterface/" service="InsertService" payload="envelope" wsdlLocation="AFISINSERT.wsdl" doc:name="CXF" configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration"/>
    <component class="Transform" doc:name="Java"/>  
    <logger message="String message : #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>      
</flow>
```

I'm sending a POST request with the following structure:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:type="http://XXX/ZZ/WWW/YYY/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<input>
    <type:Data>
        <type:id>1</type:id>
        <type:sampleType>?</type:sampleType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <type:tenprint>
                <type:width>600</type:width>
                <type:height>800</type:height>
                <type:format>S</type:format>
            </type:tenprint>
    </type:Data>
    <type:PersonID>123</type:PersonID>
    <type:Priority>3</type:Priority>
</input>
<soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My java class here:

```
public class CLASE extends AbstractMessageTransformer{

public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {

String mensajeString = new String();    
     try {
        return message.getPayloadAsString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

By using Mule variables, I'm able to access to the nodes of the xml using XPATH, in the log, the xml request is correctly printed. I have tried so many things, but I cannot access to the payload information correctly, How can I get the information stored into the Payload using JAVA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose one of two options, to get the information stored in `<type:Data>` from Java code.

1. Parse the POST data into an XML document inside the Java code:

   ```
   public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
       BufferInputStream payload = (BufferInputStream) message.getPayload();
       DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
       Document doc = dBuilder.parse(payload);

       String typeData = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("type:Data").item(0).getTextContent();
   ```
2. Use XPATH to extract the required data, store it in a variable, and then proceed in the Java code:

   ```
   public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
       String typeData = message.getInvocationProperty("variableName");
   ```